# My layout mixes itself if I make the window smaller

Tags: html, css, layout

if I make the window of my browser smaller, than the buttons will mixed and the logo goes a little bit down. I want that the buttons and the logo should still be there where they are. How can I realize that?
Thank you in advance!

The html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
<html>
    <body>
            <div id="header">
                <table>
                        <th>
                            <img id="logo" src="images/logo.jpg">
                        </th>
                        <th>
                            <div id="menue_bar">
                                <a href="#">Home</a>
                                <a href="#">News</a>
                                <a href="#">Contact</a>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                </table>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the css:

```
#menue_bar {
    padding: 24px;
    border: #999 1px dashed;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
#menue_bar > a{
    font-size:17px;
    padding: 12px 24px; 
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transition: background 0.3s linear 0s, color 0.3s linear 0s;    
}
#header {
    background-color: #FFFF;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: you need responsive html ?

Answer (score 2):

You need a responsive design.
There are many ways to do this, some simple rules would be to :

1. Avoid fixed sizes (px) and start using units that scale (em, %, etc.)
2. Use CSS media queries

Reasoning:

1. Fixed sized units are just that, fixed size. Your layout will look great at 1 screen/window size but will be unpredictable at others
2. Certain screen sizes need major layout changes that can't be accomplished with scaling units, for these you will need a different set of CSS and a way to apply this set of CSS to the corresponding screen size, hence media queries.

However there are a lot of frameworks that do all of this for you, see [skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/) and [Boostrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)